# HTML/CSS Need help setting variable for simple circle graph

Tags: php, html, css, variables, web

Below is the code that I am having issues with. I have attempting to set a variable with php that CSS would read. I'm not new to coding, but I am new to web development as of 4 days ago.

```
  <?php
    $perc = "70";
    header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
    ?>

    <style>
    .pie {
      width: 100px; 
      height: 100px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background: green;
      background-image:
      linear-gradient(to right, transparent <?php echo $perc ?>, #499 0);
    }
```

Comment: What is the output that is generated? what issue are you facing with this code?

Comment: I think you are missing the % sign.

Comment: background overrides background-image. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Why not just use ChartJS?

Comment: This is a snippet of the code. The goal is to be able to create scripts that edit what % the circle chart is filled up. I added the % and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that "perc" means percent, you need to pass the percent symbol to CSS at some point in your code.

You can either use:

```
$perc = "70%";
```

Or:

```
linear-gradient(to right, transparent <?php echo $perc; ?>%, #499 0);
```

Comment: I tried adding the % to $perc and inside the actually linear-gradient line and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Start your CSS files with this PHP (and name it style.php):

```
    <?php
        $perc = "70%";
        header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
    ?>


    .pie {
      width: 100px; 
      height: 100px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background: green;
      background-image:
      linear-gradient(to right, transparent <?php echo $perc ?>, #499 0);
    }
```

Then call your CSS with the PHP file name in your HTML file:

```
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/style.php' />

    <input type="text" name='aaa' class="pie">
    <input type="text" name='aaa' >
```

Comment: I think this is the correct path I just need some additional assistance. I will have two different files. 1 named style.php and another named index.html. The second file (index.html) will have the <link rel...etc.. portion of the code. Correct? Sorry - I am a little confused by your response. Thank you for helping.